# mysqli count group by multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I would like to count rows based on the involvement of multiple columns

```
+----+---------------+--------------+
| ID | ticket_holder | ticket_buyer |
+----+---------------+--------------+
| 1  | jim           | jim          |
+----+---------------+--------------+
| 2  | sue           | gor          |
+----+---------------+--------------+
| 3  | gor           | jim          |
+----+---------------+--------------+
| 4  | nic           | jim          |
+----+---------------+--------------+
```

My tickets table looks like that, and I want to return an array that includes each person's id but also has a count of how many shows they're involved with as a ticket buyer or ticket holder (but not counting twice for both).

The result I want is an array like this

```
+---------+--------------+
| user    | ticket_count |
+---------+--------------+
| jim     | 3            |
+---------+--------------+
| gor     | 2            |
+---------+--------------+
| sue     | 1            |
+---------+--------------+
| nic     | 1            |
+---------+--------------+
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with code so that we know what you have tried so far? Thanks!

Comment: And it would be excellent if you could provide a fiddle with some example data, https://www.db-fiddle.com/  to create your Tables you can run `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` against you DB to get the SQL for the create table.  Or if the data is just test data you can do an export to the screen and paste that in there.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is count the number each person as ticket holder or buyer separately, and subtract where they are both.

To count how many times each person is a holder or buyer you can use these queries

```
select count(*), ticket_holder from table group by ticket_holder
select count(*), ticket_buyer from table group by ticket_buyer
```

To count how many times a person is both buyer and holder:

```
select count(*), ticket_buyer from table where ticket_holder=ticket_buyer group by ticket_buyer
```

These can be combined into a single query but it's maybe easier to understand and maintain if you do the calculations outside the database